# How to get buttons to return back to its original state after a series of clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

I am making a web application where the user will click on a number of different buttons, the border of these buttons will then change color, however whenever the user clicks on the enter button I want the buttons that were previously clicked to change back to their original state.

Any help is appreciated

```
protected void btnTeam1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    btnTeam1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow; 
    lblMessage2.Text = "Home Team"; 
} 
protected void btnTeam2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    lblMessage2.Text = "Away Team"; 
    btnTeam2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow; 
}
```

The user then goes and clicks an enter button which inputs data into a DB. Whenever the enter button is clicked I would like the buttons that have been clicked to have no yellow border

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code you have already written please?

Comment: protected void btnTeam1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnTeam1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblMessage2.Text = "Home Team";
                
        }

        protected void btnTeam2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage2.Text = "Away Team";
            btnTeam2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }

Comment: The user then goes and clicks an enter button which inputs data into a DB. Whenever the enter button is clicked I would like the buttons that have been clicked to have no yellow border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to the Click function for your enter button:

```
btnTeam1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
btnTeam2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
```

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the check icon - you can vote it up too if you like :)